# How to adjust the digit size of my numeric scale in qgis print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In QGIS Print composer one can add a scale and switch from "simple frame" to "numeric frame" as shown in the following image.

[image]

How do I change the size of the shown digits? My aim is to set the digit size the same as my text elements. Is that possible?

Comment: Item Properties -> Display -> Font

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for a long time yesterday and found it immediately now. Sometimes you just need a good sleep :D